# Change color of specific code words in xcode

Tags: c++, xcode

In Xcode, is there a way to change the color of specific words in the code you write? (I know you can change broad color schemes but I want this to be specific)

I'm asking because I have a C++ code with a LOT of "cout" debugging outputs. I specifically want the word "cout" to be a different color from everything else, so that when I browse through my code I can immediately identify the debugging lines.

Is there a way this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Are you coding C++ on Xcode? That's not a good practice. You should use another editor like Sublime Text or Code::Blocks for that. There you can chose from multiple scheme or make a customized theme of your choice. It's not possible to customize Xcode to that extent.